# How do I properly manage multiple Git clones of an SVN repositorie?

Tags: git, svn

One of the projects I work on uses a SVN repository to manage its code.  I would like to use Git for version control on all of my machines, as well as be able to host a copy of the repository on GitHub.  I have a graphic depicting how I would like things to be setup or merged, but I can't post it yet.

I've managed to use `git svn clone` to clone the SVN trunk to my machine, and can then use Git to branch locally, but when I tried to merge the changes from my development branch back into master so that I could `git svn dcommit` them I received the following error:

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history

I then tried to undo the merge and `git svn rebase` and I received this error:

> Unable determine upstream svn information working tree history

Clearly I am doing something incorrectly, but I can't seem to find any information on how to correct these errors that works.  As well, the posts I do find on the subject offer no advice on how to avoid ending up in the same situation again in the future.

So, that's what I've managed to do incorrectly.  There are also several things I haven't managed to do at all when trying to bridge the SVN repo and my local Git clones.  The first of which is tracking only one of the many branches present in the SVN repo.  Most of the branches there I don't care about, so I would like to avoid the overhead of syncing with all of them.  What is the proper way to tell Git to track an individual SVN branch?  If a new branch is added to the SVN repo after I have done my `git svn clone` will I be able to start tracking it?

Lastly, I would like to be able to host a copy of my Git repo on GitHub and then use that to synchronize my development work between my machines.  On my first attempt at this it seemed that none of the SVN related information got pushed to the GitHub repository.  When I cloned the repo from GitHub to a new machine and then attempted to run `git svn rebase` it failed.  Is there a way to have the necessary SVN info pushed/cloned properly by Git, or will I have to re-add the SVN referencese and metadata on each machine after I've cloned the Git repository?

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You work on getting them to move to git.  git-svn git still doesn't handle `svn:mergeinfo` well.  It doesn't update the property as much as it replaces it. (This isn't a knock on git - making this work would be a largely wasted effort)

Your best option is to suck it up and use svn until they move to something more palatable.  It's better than it used to be, but using git-svn may spit in the svn soup for the rest of the team.